# Show a DatePicker when touching a static table cell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uidatepicker, xcode4.2

I want to create a something like the birthday field in the contacts app. When editing a contact and touching the birthday table cell a date picker appears, I can change the date and the values are show in the cell immediately.

There are tutorials on the web or Apples demo code "DateCell", but I want to use the cool new storyboarding feature of xcode 4.2. I have just a few static table cells and no corresponding data source thus no `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

I already tried to use a text field inside the table cell and replace the default keyboard with a date picker by setting the `inputView` property. But the behaviour is not the same as the birthday cell, i.e. there is always a cursor visible.

Any ideas?

Best regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can make a UIDatePicker appear (like in the contacts app) by adding a touch event that when triggered causes a UIDatePicker (inside a UIView) to animate up from below the bottom of the screen.

Get the UIDatePicker to update a variable that your cell gets its data from, then reload the tableView when the UIDatePicker's value is changed.

Finally add a touch event to the ViewControllers background that when clicked causes the UIDatePicker to animate down off the bottom of the screen if its currently visible.

NB: I have not used storyboarding, so don't know if it affects my answer or not.